Unable to locally save some models locally with SentenceTransformers
Tried many times to have SentenceTransformers and having stripped down my code to the following:
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
modelPath = "/Users/bob/.cache"
model = SentenceTransformer("Salesforce/SFR-Embedding-Mistral")
model.save(modelPath)

always fails with timeouts(?) while downloading the model, not always at the same exact spot. Here follows an example:
llm-fast-py3.11bob /Volumes/2TBWDB/code/llm_fast [main] $ /Volumes/2TBWDB/code/llm_fast/.venv/bin/python /Volumes/2TBWDB/code/llm_fast/llm_fast/prove/scarica
.py
modules.json: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 229/229 [00:00<00:00, 413kB/s]
config_sentence_transformers.json: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 123/123 [00:00<00:00, 288kB/s]
README.md: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 85.3k/85.3k [00:00<00:00, 756kB/s]
sentence_bert_config.json: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 54.0/54.0 [00:00<00:00, 187kB/s]
config.json: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 663/663 [00:00<00:00, 1.99MB/s]
model.safetensors.index.json: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 22.2k/22.2k [00:00<00:00, 29.4MB/s]
model-00001-of-00003.safetensors: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 4.94G/4.94G [00:46<00:00, 106MB/s]
model-00002-of-00003.safetensors: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 5.00G/5.00G [00:46<00:00, 107MB/s]
model-00003-of-00003.safetensors: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 4.28G/4.28G [00:40<00:00, 107MB/s]
Downloading shards: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 3/3 [02:14<00:00, 44.72s/it]
Loading checkpoint shards:  33%|███████████████████████████████▋                                                               | 1/3 [00:17<00:35, 17.53s/it]zsh: killed     /Volumes/2TBWDB/code/llm_fast/.venv/bin/python 
/Users/bob/.pyenv/versions/3.11.7/lib/python3.11/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:254: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '

Same happens with other largish models such as intfloat/e5-mistral-7b-instruct
I have a good 200MBit fiber connection. Can I do anything else to save these models locally?
Python 3.11.7 - sentence-transformers 2.6.1 - Mac M1 16GB with Sonoma 14.4.1 - 55GB free disk space

What is your python version? What is your transformers version? What machine (Linux/Mac/windows) do you have? And how much RAM and diskspace do you have on the machine?

My bad for not having included all of this. I apologize and will add  editing to the original post. Thanks a lot

any error messages?
